# How to get the list of zipcodes/theaterid of theaters listed in moviefone.com

Tags: java, movie

HI I need to find the showtimings in all the theaters of US. I gather that I can get the information of a perticular theater using http://gateway.moviefone.com/movies/pox/closesttheaters.xml?zip=zipcode .. but i dont have the list of zipcodes and theaterid's
can someone help me with that

Comment: the link doesnt seem to be working..

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what it is you are doing, but I suspect that you are using an unpublished web API to snarff content from the moviefone services.

Beware.

If that is what you are doing, it is likely to fall foul of the AOL Terms of Service.

---

> I will use this data for a feature in a site (which is going to be plublished soon.Sorry I cannot provide much information abt this site because my client has asked me to keep it confidential).

The fact that you are doing this for a client does not absolve you of legal responsibility for your actions.  And, in fact, it potentially exposes your client to legal risk as well.  If AOL decide to sue someone over this, you both could be named as defendants.

Another possible outcome is that AOL could use technical means to prevent your systems from snarffing the data.

> Can you please tell me any other site or list of sites which provide API for theater showtimes or from where I can snarf data on a weekly basis.

No I can't.

The point is that this data you are snarfing costs *someone* a *significant* amount of money to create / assemble / manage.  AOL will paying at least part of that bill, one way or another, and they won't take kindly to someone (like your client) freeloading off them and (potentially) taking away their business as well.

Comment: I will use this data for a feature in a site (which is going to be plublished soon.Sorry I cannot provide much information abt this site because my client has asked me to keep it confidential). Can you please tell me any other site or list of sites which provide API for theater showtimes or from where I can snarf data on a weekly basis.

Comment: I dont think they are putting any man power to assemble data to their site instead they too are using some resource on the net .. anyways I think there is a open sourced site which provides the same info .. that be  http://opensocial.flixster.com/igoogle/showtimes?movie=all&date=20120417&postal=52302&country=us